# Passing DropdownList value inside grid to the grid itself

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I've defined a DropdownList inside a KendoGrid. The DropdownList it's in a column on that Grid and it's showing the fields that come from the datasource correctly but, when I select one of those fields in the dropdown, it isnt passing/updating it's value to the grid itself.

I know that I need to use the change event to pass the value there but am not being able to do that somehow.

Can you help? I'll drop an image with the current code.

Thank you for the help.

```
if ('@viewMode.ToUpper()' == "EDIT") {
    var grid = e.sender;
    var items = e.sender.items();
    items.each(function (e) {
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
        var promtypedropdown = $(this).find('.equipDropDownEditor');
        $(promtypedropdown).kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetPromoTypesCodeDetail", "Omni")'
                    }
                },
                width: 150,
                schema: {
                    data: function (response) {
                        return response.data.data;
                    },
                }
            },
            change: function(e){                             

                var uid = $(e.sender.element).closest("tr").attr('data-uid');
                var model = $("#omniDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
                model.PROMOTION_TYPE = this.text();
```

Comment: Publish your code, not images of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future, I got it working adding the this line of code:

```
model.set("PROMOTION_TYPE", this.text());
```

Comment: It is nice from you to have answered to your own question. It would be even better to accept it so people would know it works without even before reading it.